# How to avoid the break of framed/shaded?

Tags: page-breaking, framed

I have a problem with the `framed` environment. I am writing a document (article), and several parts of it have a gray background. Unfortunately, when a new page comes, such a shaded environment is cut in half :(

How can I avoid this? (with no use of `\newpage...`)

Example: In the document generated by this code, I would like the second shaded environment to be placed in the second page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.75}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{shaded}
\begin{shaded}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it sort of defeats the purpose of the `framed` package, you may enclose every `shaded` environment within a `minipage` (of width `\linewidth`)  to prohibit page breaks. In my example I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the defintion of the `shaded` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.75}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{shaded}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{shaded}{\end{minipage}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{shaded}
\begin{shaded}
Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text\\Text
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```